Compactness and convexity of a set of matrices
I want to know if the set of positive semi-definite matrices with trace at most one, i.e., the set
$$A := \{A \in \mathsf{PSD}(n;\mathbb{R}) \,\mid\, \text{trace}(A) \text{ is at most one}\} $$
is convex and compact? I think it is convex as trace is a linear operator and then the convexity follows from the definition.
I think it is also compact being a close and bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, but I'm not sure. Can anyone suggest how to proceed?

Edit : I misread the definition of $A$.
You are right. Linearity of the trace plus the fact that the space of PSD matrices is convex make $A$ convex. A subset of a finite dimensional vector space is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded. In infinite dimension, compact implies closed and bounded but the reciprocal is false.
We are in one of the rare cases where showing compactness directly is easier than showing boundedeness and closeness (unless you assume some well-known but quite hard to prove results, like the continuity of the eigenvalues). Let $(M_k)$ be a sequence of $A$. Let us write for all $k$,
$$
M_k = U_kD_k\ ^t\!U_k,
$$
where $U_k$ is orthogonal and $D_k$ is diagonal. The space of orthogonal matrices is compact thus we may assume up to an extraction that $(U_k)$ is a convering sequnce. Let us write $U_k \rightarrow U_\infty$. Similarly, $(D_k)$ can be viewed as a sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (the $n$ diagonal coefficients).
Each $M_k$ is PSD so the coefficients of $D_k$ are non-negative and $\mathrm{tr}(M_k)$ is the sum of these coefficients and is bounded by $1$. We deduce that each of these coefficients is bewteen $0$ and $1$. In other words, the sequence $(D_k)$, seen as elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is bounded. Up to an other extraction, we may assume that $(D_k)$ converges. Let us write $D_k \rightarrow D_\infty$.
By continuity of the transpose and the product,
$$
M_k \rightarrow U_\infty D_\infty\ ^t\!U_\infty.
$$
Let $M_\infty$ be this limit, which exists up to an extraction. As $U_\infty$ is orthogonal and $D_\infty$ is diagonal, $M_k$ is symmetric. The condition of being non-negative is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ so each coefficient of $D_\infty$ (i.e. each eigenvalue of $M_\infty$) is non-negative. Similarly, their sum is bounded by $1$ so $\mathrm{tr}(M_\infty) \leqslant 1$.
We deduce that $M_\infty \in A$ so $A$ is compact.

The condition is $tr(A) \le 1$ not $tr(A) \ge1$.

Yes, the condition is $\text{trace}(A) \le 1$, but I think the proof follows similarly and it should be bounded and thus compact. @daw

Misread your post then. Still you need to prove boundedness.

Nope, you are correct, the requirement is $\text{trace}(A) \le 1$. Doesn't the bounded follows? @daw

Sorry, I misread, I edited the post.
